# PHP trouble deleting just one account

Tags: php

Okay. I have the PHP code working now. Thank you for the suggestions. Turned out to be the no quote around the string thing.

The PHP says that it works, but when I go into mySQL database the record is still there. What could be going on?

(pre-edited version) I am try to delete one user account form a record containing many. I can get the PHP to delete all the records, and I am get the PHP to echo the account that I want to delete, however, I am having trouble combining the two things. I think it's because I am still struggling with a basic understanding of the syntax. I've tried many combinations at this point, and none have worked.

The code is below:

```
//echo "{$_SESSION['email']}";

$id="{$_SESSION['email']}";
$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=user_id";



if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $con->error;
}
```

The echo that I have commented out shows the value of the item I am trying to delete.

Comment: you have `$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=user_id";`, but you meant to do `$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=$id";` -> `=$id`, not `=user_id`. Also, since `$id` is an string (`$_SESSION['email']`), you need to wrap it in quotes - `$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";`

Comment: And I kept wondering why the $id wouldn't work. That was one of my many tries. The issue was the no quotes around the string. Got it. When I do this, however, it says the delete was successful, but the record in mySQL database is still there. What might be going on? (I'm going to restart my computer just in case. Restarting seems to clear up many of the issues I have with MySQL Workbench).

Comment: If it says `Record deleted successfully`, but the row is still there, then it did not find a row to delete with `user_id=$_SESSION['email']`. Are you sure that you use an email for the `user_id`, and not `user_email`?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you tell the database to remove any user where the `user_id` is equal to the value of the said `user_id`. You never pass the id in to the query.

That means that you are telling the database to remove all entries that have its own `user_id` as `user_id`. Which is all.

Use a prepared statement and pass the `$id` variable in instead.

```
$id= $_SESSION['email']; // Don't need the "". 
//And make sure that it is a email that you are after, cause the the value of this should be a email address. 
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=:id";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now you may wonder why you should use prepared statements instead of just a raw query?
Well, I would guess that your session parameter is fetched from some type of user input. When it comes to user input, it could be pretty much anything passed, not just the value you are expecting.
If you just do a raw query, and the value in the session parameter is malicious, this would result in something called a `sql injection`. And that is not good.
Prepared statements will give you a safety vs sql-injections.

For more info about this, google "prepared statements and sql injections".

Answer (score 0):

```
$id="{$_SESSION['email']}";
$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";



if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $con->error;
}
```

You need to specify the ID you want to delete.

Comment: `$id` is a string -> `$_SESSION['email']`, so it needs to be wrapped in quotes

Comment: moving the `$id` inside the double quotes is the same as concating it at the end/outside the double quotes, so your edit did not change anything. It needs to be `"DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";` OR `"DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='".$id."'";` notice the single quotes `'` around the `$id`?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I am new to PHP programming.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the id from the email like this :-

```
$kl = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users where user_email='$id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($kl)){
$user_id = $row['id'];
}
```

// you got the id of the user now;

```
  $sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=$user_id";
if($sql){print '<script>alert('Success')</script>';}
```

Comment: Your presuming the email isn't the ID which from the users current query it would be. Also if this were the solution a sub query would be quicker. `DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id= (SELECT id FROM users where user_email='$id')`

Comment: yea i just missed that it had a easier way but i did it via the most fundamental steps that will also help in learning , he can also edit other things while deleting updating somethings and others.